# I've been trying to solve this since yesterday , PHP blacklist

Tags: php, security

I've been trying to make a blacklist on a form submission, how can i make it work.. , so that it will check each array on explode..

```
if(isset($_POST["username"])and isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $black = file_get_contents("blacklist.txt");
    $array = explode(" ",$black);
    if(empty($username)or empty($password)) {
        echo '<h1> Must enter fields </h1>';
    } else if(strpos($username,$array[0])!==false or strpos($password,$array[1])!==false) { 
        echo 'Must not contain:'. $array[$count];
    } else if($username == "dersus" and $password == "123456") {
        echo 'You have been logged in';
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem now?

Comment: What does `$array` look like??

Comment: what does `$count` contain? Btw, what's the error you're getting?

Comment: hey $array looks like $array[0] = "ftp" array[1] = "http" i don't want the form submission to contain any links, ftp http, domains whatever